# Running Linux Docker Containers on Windows Server 2019

Tags: docker, linux-containers, windows-server-2019

I am exploring docker for one of my company project. In this project I need to run the MemCached on CentOS and I prefer to run this in a docker container. I have successfully able to run this on Windows 10 machine with Docker Community Edition installed. But our project needs Windows Server 2019 in production and I want to run the container of same image (MemCached on CentOS) on windows server 2019. I googled a lot and found a [link](https://www.altaro.com/msp-dojo/linux-containers-windows-server-2019/) for running Linux Containers on Windows Server 2019. But as per the above link we are installing docker package in **Preview** version. I believe that this Preview version I should not use in Production. Is my understanding is correct or not?
Also is there any other stable released way to run Linux containers on Windows Server 2019.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you have any news? Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

As per the Preview version you can remove the `-RequiredVersion preview` tag and then install. The process will install Docker Enterprise Edition on Server 2019 and not the CE version as the one for WIN 10. 
If the container you want to run is a Linux container then you may face some tough times reason being

- The containers(linux) runs on Server 2019 using LCOW way and the LCOW way is an experimental feature.
- You said that you want to run container in Production environment and I would say not to use and experimental feature for Production.

Incase you need to run the containers on a server edition of Windows ie Server 2016 or Server 2019 you can go with the Docker CE (ie the same .exe that works on Win 10).
One important point to note is that on server 2016 all the docker versions are not supported. 
Docker 2.0.0.31259 is the supported version of Docker on Server 2016.(Latest Docker 2.1.0.3 does not work on server 2016 but it works on Server 2019

Note : I face the same issues as you face ie you want the run the containers on Server 2019. The above are my findings so far. There is no clarity from windows side about how to run docker containers. Please refer to my answer :[Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/970802/how-to-run-linux-docker-container-on-windows-server-2019/980454#980454) for better understanding

Comment: Thanks. But I am just curious that why running Linux containers on Windows server 2019 is so difficult. Who want to use windows containers on Windows server 2019? The only good and easy solution for running linux containers on Windows server 2019 should be using MobyLinux.

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling with the same issue for some time, and for me the only working combination of *Windows Server* and *Docker* that can effectively run with Linux containers is *Windows Server 2019 Standard Edition* with an edge release *Docker Desktop Community 2.1.3.0* published on 2019-09-16.

The link to read about edge releases and to download them is:
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/edge-release-notes/

In my case, there was also an issue of nested virtualization, since my *Windows Server* is installed on *VMware* machine, and *Docker* requires *Hyper-V* inside *Windows Server* in order to work.

Fixed that issue according to instructions provided here:
https://doitfixit.com/blog/2014/03/06/qhyper-v-components-is-not-runningq-nested-in-vmware-workstation/

Answer (score 1):

as far as my understanding goes, it is experimental feature, however it can be done and works quite OK. 
The only requirement is that this feature works on server with hypervisor enabled.
Follow this link: https://www.altaro.com/msp-dojo/linux-containers-windows-server-2019/ for further instructions on how to set it up.

Comment: This article was the best thing I was able to find when I had the same issue.